# Django admin - User and group extend

Tags: python-3.x, django

Iam trying to update my user model in Django's admin Panel.

I want to add a field/column in Admin panel named "Group" for Users. This field will have the option to select any value from the existing Groups (single option only/Dropdown).

I tried to search for the document but I couldnt found out the relevant information to manipulate the User Admin panel. Although I do found a few blogs and video where they have created a new app and extend the User model.

Is it possible to update Admin panel for User? Please suggest any document or blog or any approach to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to extend the user model in models.py, and also to use Inlines to reflect the changes to the admin site. Both of these steps are performed by Julia in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXZ3ntGp_Xc
The documentation for Inlines can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/).

Comment: That solves a lot of problems. Thanks Muhammad!

Answer (score 0):

So in your admin.py you can extend UserAdmin and in Permissions if you add groups it will create a group assignment to your user create form in admin.

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreateForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (('is_active', 'groups'), )}),
    )
```